# Calculating Expectation of Stochastic Volatility

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility

I have a question while reading THE NELSON–SIEGEL MODEL OF THE TERM
STRUCTURE OF OPTION IMPLIED VOLATILITY
AND VOLATILITY COMPONENTS by Guo, Han, and Zhao.

[image]

[image]
I don't understand why the above equations hold. It's easy to show that
$E_t[\sigma_{t+j}] = e^{-j\alpha}\sigma_t + \alpha \int_t^{t+j}\alpha e^{\alpha (s-t)} E_t[\bar{\sigma_s}]ds$
How does this imply the expectations above? Do we have to assume that $E_t[\bar{\sigma_s}]=E[\bar{\sigma_s}], \quad \forall t \in [0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

This exercise is quite similar to finding the mean in the Vašíček short rate model. I have shown the steps for the second expression below - something along the same lines can be done for the first expression.

Define function
$$f_{t}:=f(t,\bar{\sigma}_{t})=e^{\kappa t}\bar{\sigma}_{t}$$
Use Itô on the function
\begin{align*}
    \text{d} f_{t}&=\kappa e^{\kappa t}\bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}t+ e^{\kappa t}\text{d}\bar{\sigma}_{t}\\
    &=\kappa e^{\kappa t}\bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}t+ e^{\kappa t}\left(-\kappa(\bar{\sigma}_{t}-\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t})\text{d}t+\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}\right)\\
    &=e^{\kappa t}\kappa \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}\text{d}t+e^{\kappa t}\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}\\
    &=e^{\kappa t}\left(\kappa \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}\text{d}t+\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}\right)
\end{align*}
Substituting
\begin{align*}
    \bar{\sigma}_{t+j}&=e^{-\kappa (t+j)}f_{t+j}\\
    &=e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\left(f_{t}+\int_{t}^{t+j}\text{d}f_{s}\right)\\ 
    &=e^{-\kappa (t+j)}e^{\kappa t}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s}\kappa \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{s}\text{d}s+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}\\
    &=e^{-\kappa j}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s}\kappa \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{s}\text{d}s+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}
\end{align*}

We can then find the expectation
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}_{t} \left[ \bar{\sigma}_{t+j} \right] &=\mathbb{E}_{t} \left[e^{-\kappa j}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s}\kappa \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{s}\text{d}s+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}\xi \bar{\sigma}_{t}\text{d}w_{t}\right]\\
    &=e^{-\kappa j}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s}\kappa \mathbb{E}_{t} \left[\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{s}\right]\text{d}s
\end{align*}
as the stochastic integral has mean 0. Assuming that $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}$ is a martingale, i.e. that $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}=\mathbb{E}_{t} \left[ \bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{s} \right]$ for $t<s$:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}_{t} \left[ \bar{\sigma}_{t+j} \right]&=e^{-\kappa j}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}\kappa e^{-\kappa (t+j)}\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s} \text{d}s
\end{align*}
We know that
$$\int_{t}^{t+j}e^{\kappa s} \text{d}s=\frac{e^{\kappa (t+j)}-e^{\kappa t}}{\kappa}$$
So
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}_{t} \left[ \bar{\sigma}_{t+j} \right] &=e^{-\kappa j}\bar{\sigma}_{t}+\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}(1-e^{-\kappa j})\\
    &=\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}+e^{-\kappa j}\left(\bar{\sigma}_{t}-\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_{t}\right)
\end{align*}
This was the second expression shown with $\tau:=e^{-\kappa}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mmencke. So, the assumption of martingale property of $\bar{\bar{\sigma_t}}$ is necessary. What should you assume on $\bar{\sigma_t}$to get the first conditional expectation?